# Crontab setting - execute script every 55 minutes

Tags: linux, export, cron, scheduler

I found a interesting thing during creation of my `crontab` setting.

I used this command:

```
crontab -e
```

and fill this line:

```
*/55 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/user/Documents/script.sh $2>/dev/null
```

My idea was create scheduler, which start `script.sh` every 55 minutes.

But this script is execute in this times (for example):

```
08:55, 09:00, 09:05, 09:55, 10:00, 10:05, ...
```

and I don't know why.

Can someone explain me that?

Comment: It should be like this: `55 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/user/Documents/script.sh $2>/dev/null`

Comment: @Hackerman That would imply the "55th minute of every hour". I think the OP is asking for "05:55, 06:50, 07:45"... i.e. every 55th rolling minute, not the 55th static minute of each hour. Jan, can you please clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the script like this and it should work.

```
 */5 * * * * [ $(( $(date +%s) / 60 % 55 )) -eq 0 ] && export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/user/Documents/script.sh $2>/dev/null
```

minute-hour-day-month-year

```
*   any value
,   value list separator
-   range of values
/   step values
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a self-replicating 'at' job. Only advantage over cron is that it is less obvious, and also if you needed it to kick off not every X minutes, but X minutes after the last job completed. So your script will just contain a line to create a new 'at' job before it exits. Something like:

```
echo "/full/path/to/my/script > /root/myScript.at.log" | at now + X minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

so every 5 minutes it will do this:

number of seconds elapsed since 1. 1. 1970 will divided by 60 = how many minutes

echo $(date +%s)
1476201056 ... **second**

echo $(( $(date +%s) / 60 ))
24603351 ... **minutes**

after that it will use modulo on count of minutes

**When result of modulo is 0, it will send TRUE value.**

And it is a typical logical **AND**

[ $((......)) -eq 0 ] **&&** export DISPLAY.. **&&** .../script.sh

**Thank you.**

It is really helpful :)